# Mysql, calculating sum() when variables are dependent on other selections

Tags: mysql, variables, sumifs

Hello great people of Stackoverflow! I have been racking my brain with the following challenge.

I have a query to calculate the sum of products sold for a particular sale which is easy enough. The second part of the challenge which is driving me crazy is this:

There are some sales which are comprised of "Bundles" meaning that the sum of the individual products does not equal the final price. In order for a sale to be a bundle it has to have a "TV" product. The TV product can be sold my itself and has an associated price, but when it's part of a bundle the price is variable. Here is what I have so far:

The pricing matrix-

```
    ProdDescription        ProductID    Rank A       Rank B   Rank C
               Phone            1        $229.00    $92.00  $18.00 
             Long Distance      2       $46.00  $46.00  $18.00 
            Internet 786K       3       $103.00     $84.00  $23.00 
            Internet 1.5M       4       $113.00     $94.00  $23.00 
            Internet 3M         5        $118.00    $99.00  $23.00 
            Internet 10M        6       $123.00     $104.00     $23.00 
            Internet 25M        7       $141.00     $113.00     $41.00 
            Ultra Internet      8       $188.00     $94.00  $23.00 
            TV                  9       $123.00     $95.00  $23.00 
            TV and Ultra Int             $311.00    $234.00     $141.00 
            TV and Phone                 $352.00    $91.00  $46.00 
            TV, Phone, & Long Dist        $398.00   $229.00     $137.00 
            TV, Phone, & any Int         $465.00    $268.00     $206.00 
            TV,Phone,Long Dist,&any Int  $515.00    $274.00     $229.00
```

As you can see I haven't assigned productID's to the bundles, b/c I tried creating a separate product id for bundles and even thought about using php to  programically assign the product id based on a set of rules if the individual products are selected, but then I lose the ability to ultimately count/query the individual products that comprised that bundle/sale.

Am I overthinking this? Is it possible to do just utilizing SQL or at least limiting the PHP side?

Below is a table showing the calculated price of that TV product based on which bundle and ranking it belongs to.  I created this because I was thinking about referencing this table using an if statement if that TV product showed up in a concatenated calculation.

```
                                                  A      B     C 
     DoublePlay-Ultra Internet                    $123   $140    $118 
     DoublePlay-Phone                             $123   $(1)    $28 
     TriplePlay-Phone & Long Distance             $123   $91     $101 
    TriplePlay-Phone & Internet 786K               $133      $92     $165 
    TriplePlay-Phone & Internet 1.5 M             $123   $82     $165 
    TriplePlay-Phone & Internet 3M                 $118      $77     $165 
    TriplePlay-Phone & Internet 10M                $113      $72     $165 
     TriplePlay-Phone & Internet 25M              $95       $63      $147 
    TriplePlay-Phone & Ultra Internet             $48       $82      $165 
    QuadPlay-Phone & Long Dist & Inter 786K        $137      $52     $170 
    QuadPlay-Phone & Long Dist & Inter 1.5 M       $127      $42     $170 
    QuadPlay-Phone & Long Dist & Inter 3M          $122      $37     $170 
    QuadPlay-Phone & Long Dist & Inter 10M         $117      $32     $170 
    QuadPlay-Phone & Long Dist & Inter 25M         $99   $23     $152 
    QuadPlay-Phone & Long Dist&  Ultra Inter        $52      $42     $170
```

This question is getting ridiculously long so I'll stop there, but please does this make sense, does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you so much!

Comment: Where 'any int' is offered, under what circumstances would 'ultra' not be selected? Is it related to local availability?

Comment: Ultra is the highest/fastest speed. It would be included in an "or()" type caculation if we were testing for any internet, however as far as Double Play bundle is concerned, Ultra is the only speed internet that qualifies for that first double play, TV & Ultra. Does that make sense? Thank you again for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Consider product id with 9 digit...
I will assign the product as follows

when they purchase TV it can be
segregate 9 digit as follows

First digit be 1 (just to make other digit to hold zero
Second and Third digit for TV
Fourth and Fifth digit for phone
Sixth and Seventh digit for Internet
eight and ninth digit be for long distance...

Eg:

Individual items value
TV will be 1 10 00 00 00
Telephone will be 1 00 10 00 00
Internet will be 1 00 00 10 00
long distance will be 1 00 00 00 10

suppose if they order multiple

TV & Telephone - 1 10 10 00 00
Internet & long Distance - 1 00 00 10 10 
TV & Telephone Internet & long Distance - 1 10 10 10 10

(you can have 10 different combination in each TV, Internet, Telephone &  long distance) 
if there are more than 10 items in that field you can increase that to 3 digit. Remember - Integer can hold only 10 digit...

Hope this solves your problem

I

Comment: I think I understand, thank you.  So would I code that internet placeholder to increment if any internet is selected? then use the this generated code to link to a master table referencing the bundle pricing?